# If I include a file, I will get Include error

Tags: php

I have a smarty project:

in the `devidate_server.php`:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ax/ax_conf/CONSTANTS.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ax/utils/utils.php');
...
```

there I will get error, but I can not get the error information, because I am develop WHMCS, I don't know the traceback's place. Give me information is the interface is blank.

But if I comment the `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/ax/utils/utils.php');` there will not get error.

There will shows the interface content.

in the `utils.php` there is:

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/utils/http_util.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/qi_cloud_config/urls.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php');
Requests::register_autoloader();

function fetch_qicloud_access_tokens($params){

    $result = Requests::post('http://localhost:8000/o/token', [
        // headers
    'Accept'=>'application/json'
 ], $params, [
        // options
        'auth' => new Requests_Auth_Basic([QICLOUD_whmcs_pj_client_id, QICLOUD_whmcs_pj_client_secret])
    ]);

    return $result;
}
```

I don't know why I get include error, who can help me why I comment that line there will be normal?

---

**EDIT-01**

I get the error log:

> [Wed Jul 18 11:26:52.040872 2018] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 29189:tid 139662983087872] [client 118.113.136.133:29440] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/utils/http_util.php on line 9\nPHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/utils/http_util.php on line 9\nPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /usr/local/httpd/htdocs/whmcs/qi_cloud/utils/http_util.php on line 9\n', referer: http://www.example.net/clientarea.php

---

**EDIT-2**

the `qi_cloud/utils/utils.php`

```
<?php

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/utils/http_util.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/qi_cloud_config/urls.php');
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php');
Requests::register_autoloader();
...
```

the `urls.php`

```
<?php

require('./CONSTANTS.php');

define('qicloud_oauth_token_url', QICLOUD_BASE_API . 'o/token/'); //
```

the `CONSTANTS.php`:

```
<?php

define('QICLOUD_BASE_API', 'http://103.200.32.76:8000/');   
...
```

Comment: what is your error? did you already check error.log?

Comment: The brackets around your includes are pointless

Comment: Make sure you actually have file from where you try to include it. Maybe include works fine, but you get error from included code?

Comment: is Constants including utils or viceversa?

Comment: @Chopi No, there is no include `utils or viceversa`

Comment: @RendiWahyudiMuliawan How to find the error.log?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel for how to find the error log

Comment: I get the error log.

Comment: afterwards  I changed to include, still not work. but the `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/qi_cloud/libs/Requests/library/Requests.php');` is exists.

Comment: Are you using require inside utils.php?

Comment: @Dknacht See my EIDT -2

Comment: Check if file exists before including it. Probally a path error.

Comment: Now, I change the `urls.php`'s include `require('./CONSTANTS.php');` to absolute path, it works.

Comment: Yes, just what I thought. When you require or include a file that includes itself another file, you must use absolute paths to avoid this problem. The reason is that when you use relative paths, PHP takes the reference path of the file that is including , not the one that is being included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not rely on documents root.

Do something like:

require_once(**DIR** . '/relative/path/from/current/directory/file.php');

The require once will stop execute ifbfile is not there since it's require. The once will make sure you don't include the file twice if you pass by this code a second time. You should never include a file that as finction/class/constant declaration more than one. And if you use a proper IDE (like phpstorm) you will have a warning if the file path is invalid. This cannot be achieved with the document root variable.

But I don't know your exact contalext but you should check something like composer.json to handle your dependencies.

P.s. there is 2 underscore before and after the DIR magic constant but formatting on the mobile web version is limited and force bold...

Comment: I believe the problem here was not the usage of DOCUMENT_ROOT but the usage of relative paths induce the included files.